# Is 'match' the right operator for comparing object values?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am having a test result object which contains result as below .

```
$TestScenarioResult = [pscustomobject]@{

                        Test1Result = $true
                        Test2Result = $true
                        Test3Result = $true
                      }

if($TestScenarioResult -match $false)
{
     "Test Scenario is failed"
}
else
{
    "Test Scenario is Succeeded"
}
```

I am using match comparison operator to check whether any test result is failed. If so it is fail otherwise true. Though it works , is it a right way of comparison or any other proper way is there?

Comment: What is your goal? Just to determine if any result is false?

Comment: It works because `-match` operates on strings -- and the string representation of your object is `@{Test1Result=True; Test2Result=True; Test3Result=True}`, and the string representation of `$false` is `False`. It's either clumsy or elegant, depending on your point of view, but it's certainly not exactly intuitive.

Comment: Indeed, As long as any value is $false then it will -match $false. By the same token as long as any value is $true it will -match $true. So if your only goal is to check that every value is $true (or flip it and check every value is $false) then it should do what you want. If however you want to know which specific result failed, you will still need to check them individually.

Comment: Both of those comments could constitute answers.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of wanted to know the use case before presenting an answer.

Comment: @EBGreen the use case is , if any of the sub test is failed then the Testscenario is failed otherwise it is true.

Comment: In that case what you are doing is an atypical but functional way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the other answer, but you can use the hidden `.PSObject.Properties` default property to get the objects properties and then check each of their results with a loop:

```
$TestScenarioResult = [pscustomobject]@{
    Test1Result = $true
    Test2Result = $false
    Test3Result = 'someothervalue'
}

ForEach ($Result in ($TestScenarioResult.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '^Test\d.*Result'})) {
    if ($Result.Value -eq $True) {
        "$($Result.name) succeeded"
    }
    elseif ($Result.Value -eq $False){
        "$($Result.name) failed"
    }
    else{
        "$($Result.name) was unexpectedly $($Result.value)"
    }
}
```

I've added a `Where-Object` filter to the properties to evaluate only those that are named `Test[any number]Result` and then check for 3 outcomes: true, false or neither true or false.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a nicer way to do it. It will also tell you which results are true or false.

`if` will evaluate true or false without a comparison operator.

```
$HT =
@{

    Test1Result = $true
    Test2Result = $false
    Test3Result = $true
}

$TestScenarioResult = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HT

$PropMem = $TestScenarioResult | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | select -ExpandProperty name

Foreach ($Prop in $PropMem)
{
    if($TestScenarioResult.$Prop)
    {
        "Test Scenario $Prop is Succeeded"
    }

    else
    {
        "Test Scenario $Prop is failed"
    }
}
```